# How to subscribe to a DependencyProperty Change Notification

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Static Dependency Property and I need to know when its value changes so I can call a callback and update a value else where. Right now I can't do it because the callback isn't static and the Dependency change event is.

I have it currently working when the LostFocus event fires, but I'd prefer to have it wired up to whenever a change occurs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dependency property change notification passes in the object.  You can use that to map to a non-static variable:

```
static void OnThePropChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     YourClass instance = (YourClass)obj;
     instance.ThePropChanged(args); // Call non-static

     // Alternatively, you can just call the callback directly:
     // instance.CallbackMethod(...)
}

// This is a non-static version of the dep. property changed event
void ThePropChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
      // Raise your callback here... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to set up a Binding between your DependencyProperty and "elsewhere", if this is only about getting a value somewhere else.